# Protractor: preserve variable outside getText() function

Tags: function, variables, protractor, gettext, preserve

I want to preserve variable outside getText() function, so that I can match it to the values latter in the tests. Example:

Page object file:

```
this.numberOfAllLines = element(by.id('all_lines'));
this.tableCell = element(by.css('.table_results_lines'));
this.sumOfAllLinesText = element(by.id('sum_lines'));
```

Spec file:

```
var numberOfLines = '';
var newNumberOfLines = '';

describe(...
    it(...
        page.numberOfAllLines.getText().then(function(num) {
            numberOfLines = num;
        });

        newNumberOfLines = numberOfLines + 10;

        expect(page.tableCell.getText()).toEqual(newNumberOfLines);

        // doing some clicks

        expect(page.sumOfAllLinesText.getText()).toEqual(newNumberOfLines);
    });
});
```

This is not answered in [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This piece of code `newNumberOfLines = numberOfLines + 10` is async and will execute before even the assignment of `numberOfLines = num;` happens.

What you are doing is correct. Having a global variable which hold the value to be compared. But have the assignment code inside the chained promise of `getText()`.

```
it(...
        page.numberOfAllLines.getText().then(function(num) {
            numberOfLines = num;
            newNumberOfLines = numberOfLines + 10;
        });  

        expect(page.tableCell.getText()).toEqual(newNumberOfLines);
```

Comment: I'm still such a noob. Thanks, this solved my problem!

Comment: Do you know how can I can multiply values from getText() functions in this example:
`page.numberOfAllLines.getText().then(function(num) {
 numberOfLines = num;
});

page.winPrice.getText().then(function(price) {
 cost = price;
});

priceSum = numberOfLines * cost;

expect(page.tableCell.getText()).toEqual(priceSum);` Is this even possible due to async nature of Protractor?

Comment: Put this - `priceSum = numberOfLines * cost` inside the second `getText().then()`